# Uploading two files on one form?

Tags: php, file-upload, ini-set

Ok so i have the form setup perfect but only the first upload is coming through. When i debug the PHP $_FILES i get this

```
  Array ( 
        [download] => Array ( 
        [name] => Array ( [0] => 01 something.mp3 [1] => 12 Alone.mp3 ) 
        [type] => Array ( [0] => audio/mpeg [1] => ) 
        [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpqRkcOG [1] => ) 
        [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) 
        [size] => Array ( [0] => 514828 [1] => 0 ) ) )
```

As you can see I am not getting the second upload .....in the tmp directory

I was thinking of it was max_file_uploads

so i added this on top of my form

```
 ini_set('max_file_uploads','20');
```

but still nothing....any ideas

Comment: And you're not using the same POST-name for both input elements?

Comment: Are you sure the file `input` elements have unique names? What you can do is to use 'myname[]' as name for all `input` elements so that they are in an array.

Comment: they both have     <td><input type="file" name="download[]" value="" />

Comment: I'm guessing download[] was the form field name from that output Midas

Comment: i read some places that you cant set max_file_uploads outside the php.ini file and when i do phpinfo() i dont even see max_file_uploads

Comment: Are both files being uploaded the same type or are they different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the array is populating correctly, but the second file is showing an error of 1.  According to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), that error code is "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini."